# Trying to use HTML5 file picker in AppMaker

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-maker

I am trying to use the HTML5 file picker in my AppMaker app. (I cannot use Drive Picker since my app must run as the developer).

I can make the file picker appear in an HTML widget with this code:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```

However, I am having trouble getting the input item so I can call addEventListener() on it.  This does not work:

```
var widget = document.getElementById('files');
```

I also tried to get the elements by name and class name, no luck.

Has anybody done this?

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` attribute is being stripped by HTML sanitizer. You need to check `allowUnsafeHtml` checkbox to turn it off:

[image: html widget properties]

**PS**

Did you consider using [native Drive Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/)? It sounds easier than implementing file uploading/managing functionality from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about the unsafe HTML checkbox, that did the trick.  (Not sure why id is considered unsafe...)

Comment: Sanitizer is super strict because potentially you can bind it to some model's field, in other words value provided by end user.